# C# USer Interface Books - Equivalent To CLR Via C#

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I need to teach myself Winforms and user interface programming and want a decent book that will go thoroughly into the ins and outs of how to accomplish things.

Can anyone suggest a good book?

I know C# pretty well and have messed about with Winforms in the designer before.

Thank you

Comment: asking the obvious: is WinForms the *required* platform your learn?  Or would you be open to WPF/Silverlight?

Answer (score 2):

I have a couple suggestions:

[Programming Microsoft Windows Forms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735621535) (A little dated but still worthwhile)

[About Face 2.0: The Essentials of Interaction Design](http://www.amazon.ca/About-Face-2-0-Essentials-Interaction/dp/0764526413)

Comment: I'm surprised it was published in 2005; I was looking for a good WinForms book about a year ago and didn't run into that one--all I could find was ~2002 era and nothing terribly insightful

Comment: Does "Programming Microsoft Windows Forms" cover the MVP pattern with Winforms?

Answer (score 1):

Charles Petzold has written really good Windows UI development books.

http://www.charlespetzold.com/books.html

If you have to program in Winforms, then "Programming Microsoft Windows Forms" is probably your best bet. But if you want to use a more current technology (WPF), then you could use "Applications = Code + Markup
A Guide to the Microsoft Windows Presentation Foundation" from the same author